# Logstash Multiple index based on multiple path

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I'm using following configuration file for Logstash to create multiple indices, but they are not visible in Kibana. Logs are parsed, but index is not created. What do I need to change for this to work?

```
input {
    stdin{
        type => "stdin-type"
        }
    file{
        tags => ["prod"]
        type => ["json"]
        path => ["C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/log/prod/*.log"]
        }
    file{
        tags => ["dev"]
        type => ["json"]
        path => ["C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/log/test/*.log"]
        }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  if "prod" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => ["prod-log"]
    }
  }
  if "dev" in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => ["dev-log"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: We need example of your data, possibly multiple example considering you have splitting of output based on tags. Also we need logs after you run this. If your logs are parsed and printed on `stdout` then there can be problem with connection to Elasticsearch node. So you can also try to check `netstat` to check if Elasticsearch is listening on expected ports.

Comment: Do you have any error logs in logstash? Also, the `index` option in the `elasticsearch` output is not an array, remove the squared brackets, the plugin expects a string, not an array. Shoud be `index => "index-name"`.

Comment: No error in logstash but unable to create any index